# Having trouble zooming and centering on users location in MapView in iOS

Tags: ios, mkmapview, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am trying to display a map that simply captures the users latitude and longitude coordinates, and then zoom in to the user on a map.  I am able to capture the user's coordinates, but I am unable to display a map that zooms in to the users location, nor centers the map on the user.  Unfortunately, I am only able to view a map that shows the user from far away.  My relevant code is as follows:

I declare `userLoc` of type CLLocationCoordinate2D in the .h file.  I then have the following in my .m file:

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    userLoc = newLocation.coordinate;
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self showCurrentLocation];



    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        userLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        userLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }


    NSLog(@"User Latitude is %@", userLatitude);
    NSLog(@"User Longitude is %@", userLongitude);
}
```

I then have the following method that displays the actual map:

```
-(void) showCurrentLocation {

    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 55, 320, 425)];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = mapView.region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    region.center = userLoc;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;
    region.span=span;

    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];


}
```

As I said, I am able to view the map that shows the users location, but the map neither zooms in, nor does it center the map on to the user.  Can anyone see why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void) showCurrentLocation {

    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 55, 320, 425)];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = mapView.region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    region.center = userLoc;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;
    region.span=span;

    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];


}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution.  I didn't realize I was that close :-)

Comment: No problem! Sometimes the silliest thing is very hard to see and another pair of eyes helps